# react native unable to resolve module util

Tags: node.js, react-native

```
react native version 63.4 
node version 14.17.5
```

Error: `Unable to resolve module util from D:\Repos\Socket\node_modules\bson\dist\bson.browser.umd.js:` util could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

var customInspectSymbol = typeof Symbol === 'function' && typeof Symbol['for'] === 'function' ? // eslint-disable-line dot-notation
Symbol'for' // eslint-disable-line dot-notation
^
: null;

I installed new version of the npm and after run `npx react-native run-andorid` getting this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to run this command and it will be fixed

npm install util

Comment: can you clarify how this solves the issue? we are seeing this issue happen in our CI environment, but locally our react-native builds/runs android without issue

Comment: I have copied the file from my running project to the project that was causing issue. and it solved my problem.

Comment: @AftabAmin if my answer fixes your issue please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I will check this, and if solves my issue. then will definite mark it as accepted and will upvote it.